How does utilitarianism deal with threats to others which depend on your actions?
If I was told that if I don't, for example, sit down, someone would commit an act of terrorism, would I be morally obligated to sit down under utilitarianism? On one hand, it would minimise suffering, and yet on the other hand, I am not the one doing the action which increases suffering.
Then, what if that person implanted a chip in my brain which meant that if I sit down, a bomb would go off, killing and harming people. I would have a more direct link to it than the first situation, and yet they seem pretty similar, in that in both of the situations, the person is creating a situation in which my actions cause suffering.
So what would a utilitarian think the correct course of action is in each situation? Does it differ? If so, why?

Utilitarianism doesn't seem very utilitarian, in general.

@andrós What do you mean? I mean, I am an error theorist, but I haven't made that public here and I don't see its relevance

@andrós What are you talking about?

It sounds kind of like a Trolley Problem scenario, which as best I know, no method deals with adequately, because it is not really dealable. Can we make an ethical problem so heavy that we can't uplift it? Yes. Humans excel at that! It's really what we are best at.

Direct vs indirect consequences
One might consider a carried-out threat to be an indirect consequence.
Utilitarianism wouldn't draw a definitive line between direct and indirect consequences of one's actions. The question is just: what is the ultimate end result, and indirect consequences certainly forms part of that.
One should also consider how likely the indirect consequences are - the less direct consequences are, the harder they tend to be to predict.
One might also take a broader view and consider the wider effects on well-being or suffering if one were to give in to threats.
On a related note, there's been a few cases in public discourse over the last few years, where people have said (roughly speaking) that there's nothing wrong with saying something despite knowing this is likely to inspire others to violence or other crimes, because those being inspired are choosing freely to act. But this is just absurd to me (even putting questions of free will aside). If you say the words, people get hurt. If you don't say the words, they don't. The only way it would make sense to me that someone would say the words, despite knowing the likely outcome of harm (assuming there isn't some "greater good" being served by those words), is if they just couldn't care less whether people get hurt. In that case, it seems reasonable to say they're devoid of empathy or compassion.
Action vs inaction
The two scenarios you present differ in whether acting or not acting causes harm.
Moral philosophy tends to focus on the consequences of your actions, more so than the consequences of your inaction (and this isn't just specific to utilitarianism).
There is a problem to saying inaction is immoral, because there is a world full of suffering that you're not doing anything about at any given point in time. If inaction and action have equal moral value, you'd basically be compelled to spend every moment of every day committing yourself to helping others. That doesn't seem like a particularly realistic moral philosophy.
But consequentialism/utilitarianism focuses more strictly on the consequences, so one could argue that it doesn't matter that much whether it's a result of action or inaction, and if we're focusing on a limited-enough scope, you could say you're morally obligated to act (e.g. if a child is drowning and you're the only person around to be able to save them).
But even if we don't say there's a moral obligation to act, one could still say it's virtuous to do so (i.e. doing it is good, but not doing it is neutral). So we could say either it's "bad" to not act, or we can say it's neutral to not act and "good" to act.
A related answer of mine about whether you should donate all your possessions.
Side note: What's the point of utilitarianism?
People try to treat utilitarianism as a strict and formal set of concrete rules. This is usually done by those who disagree with it, and they commonly consider those concrete rules to be exactly the rules they have in mind, which often explicitly leads to a non-utilitarian outcome, which doesn't undermine utilitarianism as much as it undermines the specific rules they are choosing to use for it. But I digress.
Anyway, people treat it as a strict set of concrete rules, and there is some value in digging into that. But I'd generally recommend viewing it more as an ideal, an ideal that most people already follow most of the time. If you see someone needlessly suffering, you try to help them, to reduce their suffering. Many people also try to increase the well-being of other people, including strangers. Most people also try to refrain from intentionally inflicting needless suffering on others. Utilitarianism is basically just taking these things we already do and value, and calling the first two groups of actions "good" or "virtuous", and the last one "bad".
Suffering (or harm, more broadly) is also a fundamental building block of the justice system, and countries that don't judge something to be a crime based on whether it inflicts harm on others tend to be the ones that e.g. murder people for simply existing or trying to live their lives without imposing on anyone else, and life in such countries doesn't sound like a particularly fun time. There are also too many people in the west trying to criminalise things without much interest in discussing whether it inflicts harm, which should be very concerning.
I'm also still waiting for anyone who complains about utilitarianism to make a case for a better moral philosophy, that tells us how we're supposed to figure out what's "good" and what's "bad". There certainly are other moral philosophies, but you rarely hear about any of them, except deontology via any given religion, but that tends to rely entirely on that religion being true (which a lot of people disagree about for any given religion, and a lot of people disagree about what's right and wrong within that religion).

Thank you for the comprehensive answer. As for your last point, I personally no longer have a moral system as I believe in error theory, but I think I used to have a pretty good case for a sort of propertarian deontology. It was a bit different from anarcho-capitalist ethics so I avoided terms like NAP, but I do think libertarian ethics are worth looking into more if you haven't so far.

@edelex So is that to say, roughly, your only concern for others exists in how an outcome makes you personally feel? If you don't have a moral system, how can you argue that some things should be illegal and other things shouldn't be? How can you convince a stranger to not harm yourself or others? Would you? Can you? Do you? Not having a moral system seems to necessitate not being able to contribute anything more than saying "I prefer this" with no reason given (although one could certainly try to argue based on other people's moral systems or appeal to their emotion, but that has issues).

Pretty much, yeah. I guess I would say I do just have preferences. I don't think there are any desire-independent reasons for action. Why do you believe there are any true moral claims in the first place?

@edelex I wouldn't say moral systems have objective truth value, but rather they are things we construct with the purpose of some goal (e.g. minimise suffering). You can't get a "should" from an "is" (as per Hume), but you can get one in the context of a goal (if you want to achieve X, you should do Y). Then you can theoretically convince people of moral propositions by (a) convincing them of your goal, i.e. that they should pursue that goal, or even just that they'd prefer to live in a world where we agree on that goal, and then (b) convince them that some action is in line with that goal.

I don't even believe in instrumental oughts, although they could be taken non-literally and it might still work? But regardless, how do you even privilege one moral system over another in that situation? It would require another subjective evaluation to say that something being agreed with more makes it more favourable. It seems to end up just being purely subjective preferences, which I definitely wouldn't use moral language to describe

@edelex We are certainly subjectively deciding and agreeing on a particular goal for a moral system. The point is to try to determine some reasonable framework for how to treat other people, to live in a consistent way (much like people value consistency in epistemology), and to try to get to some agreement with others about how we should live (which is quite helpful for the functioning of society). If you don't want to call that "morality", we can instead call that "schmorality", but the function of this is the same in any case.

@edelex If you don't even accept statements like "if you want to achieve X, you should do Y": that's basically just saying Y is the action most likely to lead to outcome X. That's it. I don't really know how one could not accept that, unless it's just a semantic disagreement about the word "should" in that sentence.
